# How to install and run Theia, browser based IDE?

Tags: theia

I want to develop remotely and read about Theia. I could install the program with pip

```
pip install theia
```

But then there is no description available on how to start the program. Is it plug-in for Eclipse, or do I have to run it in docker or what?

Answer (score 1):

Theia is not an extension of the classic Eclipse project. This is not really an installable app.

If you want to run Theia locally, you can follow the tutorial of the official documentation : [Official help to setup environement](https://theia-ide.org/docs/composing_applications/).

Be sure to have Node.js 10 installed. It is not currently compatible with Node.js 12. If you want to have more than one version of Node installed on you machine, I advise you nvm ([nvm github](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)) or nvm-windows ([nvm windows github](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)).

If it can be useful, I personnally have a small bat script to launch Theia at the manner of a desktop app

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://localhost:3000
yarn start
```